# There's no drop shadow filter in Gimp

Tags: gimp

I'm in Gimp 2.8 in OSX and trying to use the drop shadow filter. But it doesn't appear in the menu. From all accounts it should be there by default. Do I need to do anything to install/enable it?

Answer (score 1):

I found it under Tools > GEGL Operation. This differs from what documentation and tutorials suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using GIMP V2.8.14 on Windows 10 and I had the same problem as above.  I also found that trying to create a drop shadow on text by Filters->Light and Shadow->Drop Shadow... didn't seem to pull up a drop shadow window, but I could get one using Tools->GEGL Operation...  I would wish that the developers of this tool would make the parameters sticky, so that the settings (X, Y, Opacity and Radius) would remember the settings I used last time.  If I'm doing the same operation on a number of text layers, resetting the parameters each time gets old fast.

After all of this, on closing a canvas I found the original Script-Fu Drop Shadow dialog box hidden under the canvas window.  It was there all the time, I just didn't see it.  I wonder if this is also the case in OSX.